# How to write down a loop on $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ concretely?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, complex-geometry

If we regard $\mathbb{S^2}$ as the complex projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$, and define a loop on its diffeomorphism group:
$$\gamma: \mathbb{S}^1\longrightarrow\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^2)$$

$$z\mapsto([x,y]\mapsto[\bar{z}^kx,y])$$
Where $|z|=1$, $[x,y]$ is the homogeneous coordinate, $k$ is an integer, how to show that this mapping defines a nontrivial loop on $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^2
)$ for $k$ odd?

Here the "nontrivial" means it is not homotopic to the constant loop $\beta(z)=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{S}^2}$, i.e. a non trivial element in the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^2
))$.

Comment: Why do you think this loop should be nontrivial?

Comment: Isn't diffeomorphism group $ =$ Autodiffeomorphism group?

Comment: Do you already know that $\operatorname{Diff}(S^2)^0$ (the identity component) deformation retracts to $SO(3)$?  Smale proved it https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-04/S0002-9939-1959-0112149-8/

Comment: @C.F.G yeah, I'd corrected it

Comment: Hint: Your loop is in $PU(2)< PSL(2,{\mathbb C})$. Lift it to a path in $SU(2)$ (the 2-fold covering space of $PU(2)$) and see what happens.

Comment: @Tyrone This loop comes from the transition functions of Hirzebruch Surfaces, namely $W_k$, which is a $\mathrm{P}^1$-bundle over $\mathrm{P}^1$, and it is determined up to that transition function, I want to use the non-triviality of this loop to show that all Hirzebruch Surfaces with $k$ odd are diffeomorphic (that is $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at a point), and that's the reason why I also added the tag "complex geometry".

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thanks for your hint, Jason, and I know it now.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for @Jason DeVito's hint, the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathrm{Diff}(S^2))$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(\mathrm{SO}(3))$, so now, it suffices to transform this loop into a loop $r$ in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Note that one can identify $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $S^2$ via the map
$$[x,y]\mapsto\left(\frac{\Re(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y^2|},\frac{\Im(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y|^2},\frac{|x|^2-|y|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2}\right)$$
where the later we use the Euclidean coordinate of the $S^2$, it is not hard to see our loop defined here $\gamma(z)=([x,y]\mapsto[\bar{z}^kx,y])$ corresponds to the coordinate transformation (if we denote $z=e^{i\theta}$):
$$\left(\frac{\Re(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y^2|},\frac{\Im(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y|^2},\frac{|x|^2-|y|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2}\right)\mapsto \left(\frac{\cos k\theta\cdot\Re(x\bar{y})+\sin k\theta\cdot\Im(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y^2|},\frac{\cos k\theta\cdot\Im(x\bar{y})-\sin k\theta\cdot\Re(x\bar{y})}{|x|^2+|y|^2},\frac{|x|^2-|y|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2}\right)$$
which write in the transformation matrix is
$$r(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos k\theta& \sin k\theta& 0\\-\sin k\theta & \cos k\theta & 0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\in\pi_1(\mathrm{SO}(3))$$
We wanna to analyse the triviality of this loop $r$ in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, we can lift it to the level of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$, one can choose a double cover from $\phi:\mathrm{SU}(2)\longrightarrow\mathrm{SO}(3)$, defined by:
$$\phi(A)=(R(A)_{ij})_{3\times3}$$
where the entry $R(A)_{ij}$ is defined by
$$R(A)_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(\sigma_iA\sigma_j A^*)$$
where $\sigma_k$ are the Pauli matrices:
$$\sigma_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\sqrt{-1}\\\sqrt{-1}&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
hence a lifted curve $\tilde{r}$ of $r$ under the covering $\phi$ in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is:
$$\tilde{r}(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\frac{ik\theta}{2}}&0\\0&e^{-\frac{ik\theta}{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$
It is a contractible curve in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ if and only if $k$ is even (this can be obtained by putting this curve into $S^3$), hence our $\gamma$ defined on $\mathrm{Diff}(S^2)$ is trivial iff $k$ is even.